# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode cannot be converted to org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.2

I'm using play2.2.1 and now I am facing the error:

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode cannot be converted to org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode

The code is like this:

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.data.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.db.ebean.*;

import views.html.*;

import java.util.*;
import models.*;
import com.avaje.ebean.ExpressionList;

import play.data.validation.Constraints.Required;

import scala.*;

import play.libs.Json;
import org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode;
public class Application extends Controller {

//create JSON data
public static Result ajax() {
    String input = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded().get("input")[0];
    ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
    if(input == null) {
        result.put("status", "BAD");
        result.put("message", "Can't get sending data...");
        return badRequest(result);
    } else {
        result.put("status", "OK");
        result.put("message", input);
        return ok(result);
    }
}
```

And the error occurs at `ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();`.
However, I confirmed that the return value of the static method `newObject()` is `org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode` by [][1]https://playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/java/play/libs/Json.html

The version of the API reference is 2.0, not 2.2, so something different exists here?
Profoundly, when I import `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode` and delete `import org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode;`, the application works well.
Can anyone explain this behavior? 
Why does the error message contradict with the API reference?

Comment: You seem to have conflicting FasterXML/Jackson libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that there are two versions of the `Jackson` library mixed up in one project. Old versions use the `org.codehaus.jackson` namespace, while newer versions use `com.fasterxml.jackson`, because they moved from Codehaus. I had the same problem, when I used a newer version of Jackson and the refactoring did not work properly. The classes are not compatible, so you have to use `com.fasterxml.jackson` consistently.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my problem was solved, but I have a question.    You said you encountered the same error when you refactored. Does that mean you tried to change a newer version from an older version and then you've hit the error?

Comment: I have had a project with a `.jar` library, which used an old version of Jackson from codehaus. I did not know the difference back then, either. However, I used a maven dependency to include `org.fasterxml.jackson`. Both classes of `ObjectNode` got mixed up on refactoring, since there were conflicts.